# How do you set the Canon 5D RAW pictures to 16 bits mode instead 8 bits mode?

Tags: raw, canon-5d-mark-ii, bit-depth

I am shooting in RAW 8 bits mode, but I can't find out where to set the camera to shoot RAWs in 16 bits modes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: AFAIK the 5D _always_ shoots 14-bit RAW files, no exceptions. Only if you switch down to JPEG mode will you be able to shoot 8-bit images.

Comment: Kate, what are you using for post processing? This is likely where you're going from 16 to 8.

Comment: RAW is RAW, if you could change it, it wouldn't be RAW!

Answer (score 15):

The 5D's native RAW format is 12bit and the 5DmkII's RAW format is 14-bit, perhaps you are thinking of when you import the image into your image editor and you can select 8-bit or 16-bit editing?

5D Specs:
http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canoneos5d/page2.asp

5DmkII Specs:
http://www.dpreview.com/news/0809/08091705canon_5dmarkii.asp